# Why is xprop -root not returning _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW?

Tags: x11

Many sources indicate that `xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` should tell me which window is currently active. Yet, when I try this command:

```
➜  ~ xprop -root _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW                                                                                                                                        
_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW:  not found.
```

I can't for the life of me ascertain why this doesn't work. I've had friends run the exact same command and they get window information.

Where should I start looking? My environment is XMonad, X started from LightDM, xorg-server 1.19.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's only available for Window Managers that implement the [Extended Window Manager Hints (EWMH) freedesktop specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/) (extensions over the ICCCM standard which `xmonad` implements), which apparently `xmonad` does not.

You'd need to use a [different Window Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints#List_of_window_managers_that_support_Extended_Window_Manager_Hints), or see if `xmonad` provides an API of its own to query that information.

Comment: Ah, terrifc! It seems that it can be added to XMonad with http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/src/XMonad-Hooks-EwmhDesktops.html. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ocharles, please feel free to edit in the instructions for how to do that with xmonad into my answer if you don't want to add your own answer.